# Per poco non + passato prossimo oppure imperfetto?

Tags: tenses

Voglio dire "I almost cried watching the film *La vita è bella*" in italiano. Dovrei dire

> Per poco non ho pianto guardando il film *La vita è bella*

oppure

> Per poco non piangevo guardando il film *La vita è bella*

?

Comment: I don't know if how to explain this in an answer, but if you look for the word "poco" in some Italian monolingual dictionaries, you can find some examples of use of the expression "per poco non". Such examples use the "imperfetto". For instance, in [Garzanti Linguistica](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=poco) you can see this example: "per poco non cadeva". And in [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/poco/), you can find these other examples: "per poco non ci cascavo anch’io; per poco non mi colpiva in testa."

Comment: Another example from [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/non/): "per poco non ci riuscivo." From [Hoepli](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/P/poco.php): "per poco non lo perdevo." From [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/per-poco): "per poco litigavamo, per poco non cadevo." Even at [Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/italiano-inglese/per-poco-non-affogavo) you can find some examples: "per poco non affogavo", "per poco non cadevo in acqua".

Comment: For me your sentences sound both good. P.S. = I did cry watching *La vita è bella*!

Comment: @CarLaTeX:  Actually, at [Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese-italiano/narrowly) you can also find "per poco non ha investito il ciclista." So, you have probably reason.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Che si tratti soltanto di una piccola sfumatura di significato su come si sta pensando al fatto (non accaduto) di piangere nel momento di proferire la frase? (azione che sarebbe già finita nel passato versus azione durativa perché ci immaginiamo piangendo mentre guardiamo il film).

Comment: @charo La sfumatura è proprio piccola, per me non c'è molta differenza...

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Posso capirlo: piccolissima, praticamente quasi inesistente.

Comment: @Charo Per me, questo imperfetto è descrittivo di un evento passato, mentre il perfetto evoca di riviverlo. Ma forse sbaglio.

Comment: La seconda suona non corretta, non saprei dire perchè. La negazione del modo durativo stona.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that "Per poco non piangevo..." would be a better translation. However if you say "Per poco non ho pianto..." no one will ever think that you're mistaking.

"I almost cried watching the film..." can be translated into Italian like: "Ho quasi pianto guardando il film...".

Comment: To me *Per poco non ho pianto* sounds more natural, but both versions sound correct. Do you have a reference/an argument for the fact that using *imperfetto* is the better translation?

Answer (score 1):

I would say "Ho quasi pianto guardando il film..."

Tra le due che hai proposto però, concordo con Charo, la seconda mi suona piú naturale anche se sono entrambe corrette.

Answer (score 0):

The CORRECT and formal form would be *Per poco non ho pianto* although *Per poco non piangevo* is colloquially used and generally accepted.

Comment: Per favore tutti quelli che hanno il voto negativo facile commentate e spiegate il perché non siete d'accordo con la risposta.

Comment: Io non ho votato negativamente, ma vedi i miei commenti alla domanda.

Comment: Non ho votato, ma credo che questa risposta sia poco utile perché manca di spiegazione su come mai la forma corretta sia la prima.